# mysql, permissions for different users to access different tables

Tags: mysql

I would like to understand how hard this is to implement.

In unix, there are unix groups where certain people with a group can access certain folders and files.

I would like to apply the same concept into MYSQL where people could only access, view certain tables or even same tables but different rows ...

How can I achieve this? Would I have to use a different database system?

Gordon

Answer (score 2):

This is a very common and simple approach. You can create users and specify which databases/tables they can access and what type of operations they can execute. See the [mysql documentation on this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)

For instance:

```
--create the user
CREATE USER 'gordon'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword';

--specify table and specific operations for that user
GRANT SELECT,UPDATE,DELETE,INSERT ON database.table TO 'gordon'@'localhost';
```